# google sheets regex matching

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to extract the "TAX YEAR TOTAL AMOUNTS DUE as of 4/22/2018" from a webpage and can't get regex match to work.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated. I need to match the text "TAX YEAR TOTAL AMOUNTS DUE as of 4/22/2018" and the dollar value since this webpage contains more than one table with a similar layout.

Thank you.

Here's the html:

```
                <TR ALIGN="LEFT">
               <TD WIDTH="50" CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;2013</TD>
               <!--TD CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;INTPT     </TD-->
               <TD WIDTH="200" CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;Property Tax Interest                             </TD>
               <TD WIDTH="125" ALIGN="Right" CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;$302.27</TD>
               <!--TD ALIGN="Right"CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;</TD-->
              </TR>







            <TR ALIGN="LEFT">
               <TD WIDTH="50" CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;2013</TD>
               <!--TD CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;ADVFEE    </TD-->
               <TD WIDTH="200" CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;Advertising Fee                                   </TD>
               <TD WIDTH="125" ALIGN="Right" CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;$4.00</TD>
               <!--TD ALIGN="Right"CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;</TD-->
              </TR>







            <TR ALIGN="LEFT">
               <TD WIDTH="50" CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;2013</TD>
               <!--TD CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;MF        </TD-->
               <TD WIDTH="200" CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;MAILING FEE                                       </TD>
               <TD WIDTH="125" ALIGN="Right" CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;$2.00</TD>
               <!--TD ALIGN="Right"CLASS="CellData">&nbsp;</TD-->
              </TR>






              <TR>
                <TD COLSPAN="2" Class = "CellTags"  ALIGN="LEFT" FONT SIZE= "+2"><B><U>TAX YEAR TOTAL AMOUNTS DUE
                  as of 4/22/2018</U></B></FONT></TD>
                <TD WIDTH="125" CLASS="CellData"  ALIGN="RIGHT"><U><FONT
                         FACE="Arial">$13,464.73</FONT></U></TD>

              </TR>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `regex` to find what you want,

```
(TAX YEAR[^<>]*)[^$]*([^<>]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/134),,, in which Tax statement string is captured to `group 1`(or `$1`), and corresponding dollar value captured to `group 2` (or `$2`)

**Edited** for you.

Thus, you can `extract` the strings what you want through the `captured groups 1, 2` in your `script`.

```
var re = /(TAX YEAR[^<>]*)[^$]*([^<>]*)/g;
var match = re.exec(variable_for_your_html_text);
Logger.log(match[1] + ': ' + match[2]);
```

Comment: Hi Thm Lee,
Unfortunately, this isn't working. It pulls a lot of html instead of the price.

Comment: Didn't you know how to retrieve the `captured strings`? Then, please retry it again, because I added some `script lines` for it. Thank you:-)